# jsFiddle code not running?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am having a problem with this code - http://jsfiddle.net/B3XkD/1/

```
function itemInSpot(drag_item, spot) {
    var oldSpotItem = $(spot).find('img');
    if (oldSpotItem.length > 0) {
        oldSpotItem.appendTo('#inventory').draggable({
            revert: 'invalid'
        });
    }
    var item = $('<img />');
    item.attr('src', drag_item.attr('src')).attr('class', drag_item.attr('class')).appendTo(spot).draggable({
        revert: 'invalid'
    });
    drag_item.remove(); // Remove the old object
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".circles").draggable({
        revert: 'invalid'
    });
    $('#inventory').droppable();
    $("#circles").droppable({
        accept: '.circles'
    })
    $('#circles,#inventory').bind('drop', function(ev, ui) {
        itemInSpot(ui.draggable, this);
    });
});
```

It runs perfect in jsFiddle, and when I copy the code onto web expression on my PC it doesn't work, only the HTML and CSS is applied, but there is no control of the images (JavaScript). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any chance you aren't loading jQuery?

Comment: hmm not sure, could you be more specific please, I only have the two files, html plus css in one, and javascipt and there is no errors

Comment: it still doesnt work on my laptop, I am copying and pasting the code into web expression?? I dont have any control over the imgs

Comment: im confident of that you forgot to implement the jquery file. please show your included files like css etc

Comment: js file I have copied exacly as its there and css - {
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
p{
margin:10px;
}
body{ font-family:Verdana; font-size:12px; }
img{ cursor: pointer;

Comment: folks are not talking about YOUR js file they are talking about the LIBRARY file for jquery that you need to include as Thomas shows below.  Please be careful when multiple people give similar advice, you may be missing the point and may need to 'step back' and read them again.

Comment: I still cant get it to work, dont know why, I have added the jquery and libary and nothing, I added these -code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js and ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.4/jquery-ui.min.js any ideas??? – user1259527

Answer (score 2):

Compare the exact code created by jsFiddle with your site.

You can sign in to jsFiddle, hit [Run] and check the source of http://jsfiddle.net/draft/, alternatively you can check the source of http://fiddle.jshell.net/B3XkD/1/show/ (not secure to check fiddles created by someone else!).

Answer (score 0):

Did you add jQuery and jQuery UI? jsFiddle adds them automatically but you'll have to do it manually in your local file:

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I still cant get it to work, dont know why, I have added the jquery and libary and nothing, I added these                       -http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js  and                         http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.4/jquery-ui.min.js                                  any ideas???

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes jsFiddle (and JavaScript beautifiers) mess up the code. The very last semicolon is edited to a different character (but you can't see the difference). Delete the last semicolon (you will need to do TWO backspaces to get rid of it) and type a new one.